# UPDATE SELECT всегда возвращает 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE
  geo 
SET 
  region_id = (
    SELECT 
      towns.region_id 
    FROM 
      towns  
    WHERE 
      towns.uid=geo.dictionary_id
  ) 
WHERE 
    geo.deleted=0
```

Пытаюсь таким запросом обновить записи в таблице, но в итоге в столбце `region_id` всегда получаю 0, хоть в таблице `towns` и есть записи соответствующие `dictionary_id` из `geo`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в действительности так таблица называется, сократил, чтобы лучше видно было

Comment: Можешь на http://sqlfiddle.com/ закинуть свои тестовые данные (две таблицы и данные в них)

Comment: Запрос в общем то неплохо выглядит. попробуйте руками, выбрать какие нибудь записи с deleted=0 найти для какой нибудь из них подходящую запись в towns по uid посмотреть какой в ней region_id. Особенно неясно почему 0, а не NULL, который был бы если бы запись вообще не нашлась, например.

Comment: @Mike в том то и дело, что когда  запускаю select с dictionary_id который есть в таблице он находит запись, но запрос вида `UPDATE
  geo 
SET 
  region_id = (
    SELECT 
      towns.region_id 
    FROM 
      towns  
    WHERE 
      towns.uid=186
  ) 
WHERE 
    geo.deleted=0= and geo.dictionary_id=186
` ничего не меняет

Comment: почему с dictionary_id. если в update у вас используется поле `uid`

Comment: вы хотите сказать, что `SELECT towns.region_id FROM towns WHERE towns.uid=186` возвращает не 0 ?

Comment: @Mike возвращает нужное значение

Comment: ну чудес не бывает, такой update обязан поменять значение. можете явно дать `update geo set region_id=N where ...` где N то значение, которое вернул вам select. Что то мне подсказывает что он то же ничего не сделает, потому что 0 пишет что то друге, триггер например

Comment: насчет триггеров не в курсе, но по идее не должно их та мбыть

Comment: ну в общем руками занесите нужно значение в одну запись и убедитесь что оно там появилось и исходя из результатов уже дальше копать. сделайте, как предлагает Алексей Шиманский, на sqlfiddle.com ваши две таблицы с несколькими тестовыми строками. Посмотрите возникает ли там та же проблема

Comment: `UPDATE geo SET region_id = 1 WHERE 1` Даже такой запрос ничего не меняет. На это поле навешен ключ, может в этом проблема? или в phpmyadmin?

Comment: Стоп. А запрос с `where dictionary_id=186` меняет ?

Comment: Эх, было бы меньше проблем, если бы вы сделали как я просил во втором комментарии...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на самом деле я пытался,но как только загрузил 2 таблицы по 5 записей и стал выполнял запрос, то полег сервак))`oop, something went wrong!`...
Проблема решилась дампом таблицы, ее удалением и залитием по новому.

Comment: @WebDev Значит у вас все таки были триггера ...

Comment: @WebDev Вы напрасно НЕ сформулировали задачу. Например, невозможно понять, что нужно делать, если для записи из `geo` нет соответствующей записи в `towns`. Оставить как есть? Изменить на NULL? Что-то ещё? А ведь в зависимости от этого текст запроса будет различным (пусть и несильно, но тем не менее).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
  geo 
SET 
  geo.region_id = (
    SELECT 
      towns.region_id 
    FROM 
      towns
    WHERE 
      towns.uid=geo.dictionary_id
  ) 
WHERE 
    geo.deleted=0 так попробуй

Comment: чем отличается мой вариант от вашего, кроме форматирования конечно?

Comment: алиаса нету перед region_id, а у тебя есть region_id и в geo и в towns

Comment: @Tiko тот region_id, что в SET точно относится к geo, т.к. поля towns видны только в подзапросе

Comment: оставалось join не правилний towns.uid=geo.dictionary_id

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE geo 
LEFT JOIN towns on towns.uid=geo.dictionary_id
SET geo.region_id = towns.region_id 
WHERE geo.deleted=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой вариант:

```
UPDATE geo, towns
SET geo.region_id = towns.region_id
WHERE geo.deleted = 0 and geo.dictionary_id = towns.uid
```